# glReadPixels() Problem in Android to reconstruct the frame

Tags: android, glreadpixels

I am working on a project on Augmented Reality with Android. The code captures the camera video, finds the marker and displays a cube on top of it. After this a motion vector (in the form of pixels moved in the x and y direction) is found. What I need to do is read the pixels from the GL layer and draw them again after moving them by the distance specified by the motion vector. 
The GL layer is specified using the GLSurfaceView class which is a transparent layer. The problem I am facing is that when I use glReadPixels() to read the pixels and convert it into a 480x800 array (nexus one screen resolution), I get 3 different portions of the cube instead of one. 
I intend to move the pixels by the motion vector after this and use glDrawPixels() to put the pixels back into the frame buffer
Please help me with the interpretation of the same. Is there something I am missing while using glReadPixels and also if there is some other function that will help me achieve the same. I was thinking of using glBlitFrameBuffer() but this is not supported by the android GL10 class.
I have attached the part of the code where I am reading the pixels and changing them to a 2D matrix along with the image of the pixels I reconstructed using MatLab. 
Sorry I am not allowed to post an image. Incase someone can help me after seeing the image, please post here and I can mail you the picture. Thanks a ton !!!

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
gl.glPixelStorei(GL10.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        IntBuffer pixels = IntBuffer.allocate(384000);

        gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, 800, 480, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE ,pixels);

            File f = new File ("./mnt/sdcard/Sahiba_PixelData_" + flag + ".txt");

                if(!f.exists())
                    f.createNewFile();
                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);

                int pixelsArr [][] = new int [480][800];
                //int temp[] = pixels.array();
                int n=0;
                for(int i=0; i<480; i++){
                    for(int j=0; j<800; j++){
                        pixelsArr[i][j] = pixels.get(n);
                            //temp[n + pixels.arrayOffset()];
                        fw.write(pixelsArr[i][j] + " ");
                        //fw.write(pixels.get(n) + " ");
                        n++;
                    }
                    //fw.write("\n");
                }

        Log.i("GLLayer", "Pixels reading and storing finished !!!");
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.i("GLLayer","Exception = " +e);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shoun't use hardcoded values because the system is allowed to change the actual size so it may lead to exceptions. Try using viewport dimensions :

```
int[] viewportDim=new int[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_VIEWPORT,viewportDim);
```

viewportDim[2] is the width and viewportDim[3] is the height.

```
gl.glPixelStorei(GL10.GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT,1);
```

I'm not sure this is correct or not but I think this should be 4 for RGBA.

You get the image as 800*480 and then you save it as 480*800? I think that supposed to 800*480 as well.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply and the knowledge about Viewport. I will use it to get the dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply and the knowledge about Viewport. I will use it to get the dimensions. Regarding the glPixelStorei function I found this info online: *GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT
Specifies the alignment requirements for the start of each pixel row in memory. The allowable values are 1 (byte-alignment), 2 (rows aligned to even-numbered bytes), 4 (word-alignment), and 8 (rows start on double-word boundaries). The initial value is 4.* Accoring to this to save byte data, I should be using param value as 1 right ? PLease correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: For the image size, when you say that I get the image as 800x480, do you mean that there are 800 rows and 480 columns or the other way round. According to the specs of the Google Nexus, the display size is 480x800 pixels which I interpreted as 480 rows and 800 columns and hence saved the image starting from the lower left corner (i.e. row 480, col 1 till col 800 and then go to row 479) Is this interpretation correct ? *Thanks a ton*

Comment: Well you must forget the device's native resultion ( 480*800 ) because you ask OpenGL to get an image for you as 800*480 ( 800 rows 480 columns ), if you save it as 800*480 you won't need to interpret it. The GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT was a guess I'm not sure it have any effect on your problem anyway.

Comment: The problem is that glReadPixels gives a 1D array so if we need to make any computations on the image we will have to reconstruct it right ?

Comment: Images are sually represented as 1D arrays, in this case what I was saying that you econstructed it the wrong way, the image you get have 800 columns 480 rows, and you save this data as 480 columns and 800 rows which is obviously not a good idea.

Comment: Is it possible to write a psuedocode for the reconstruction of the image for me ?? I am highly confused. Really appreciate the help.